# Address geolocation on own server

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, coordinates, geocoding, openstreetmap

> **Disclaimer:** Any **API** is **NO OPTION** for me because of the **vast amounts** of
>   places I want to process. I know there are plenty of services out
>   there but I'd like to have my **own solution**

Ok, after this is said here my question :)

There are platforms like [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and maybe others who are doing very well in bringing the world of maps into the open source community.

**What I need**

I have an address located anywhere in the world and I want to compute the latitude and longitude, elevation would be nice but doesn't really matter.

I've seen plenty of solutions offered around OpenStreetMap to generate custom maps, generate map tiles for a 'Google-Like' web-map experience etc.

I can't imagine how data looks like to be able to create a detailed map from it but if I am able to generate maps and even put pointers at specific POI or addresses or coordinates - it must be possible to do the thing reverse as well.

**Map gurus out there** point me to the right directions :) Any any tools running on linux, any free available database and any piece of code or algorithm to compute a 11.12345, 44.12425-style point out of my address would be helpful - as long as it does not rely on a company at stock or a web service.

So far Google did this job quite well, but they're getting d*** greedy lately :)

If this also helps me to understand how to render a pretty map I'd definitly not say no

**What I can do**

I am very good at address normalization and matching, so that's not a problem. But I need some hints and data sources where to start digging.

**EDIT1:**

Of course, possible  resolution is depending on available data quality. I'd like to be able to at least be accurate on street level worldwide. some regions dont have even streets on google so of course those bushlands don't matter for 100m accuracy

Comment: For zip codes at least, you can get free databases from the Census Bureau (Tiger).  Perhaps some address data is available from them (for the US anyway) as well?

Comment: Yeah, I know this database, very helpful already but unfortunately not for my needs in this specific case.

Comment: What resolution do you need?

Comment: good point, I'll add this to my question above

Comment: Given that the TIGER files generally have lat/long at the street segment level, why are they not appropriate for your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenStreetMap uses [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) for both address lookup and reverse geocoding. You can [install](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) a local instance on your server, [import the OSM database](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Import_and_index_OSM_data) and then run your own queries on it.