# Why do my CloudFront files seem to be missing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to understand why my CloudFront files seem to be "missing".

I am using a REST server to return map tiles and the url is something like this:

```
domain.com/1234/a/234
```

which will return a png which is a map tile.

I am wondering if it is because the url doesn't have a file extension in the request. Since it's technically a webservice request with image response, I'm not sure how to make CloudFront happy and keep my ws API in place.

Ideas or advice?

Comment: is it cloudfront with custom origin or served tiles from a s3 bucket? Also, could you have a look at my question? You seem to be a step ahead, I am interested in map tiles as well :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595768/address-geolocation-on-own-server

Comment: Please add information on your file origin configuration.